# Mysql stored function does't work. No problems indicated

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I create some mysql stored function return_tax( price float). This is basic grammar:

```
delimiter //
create function return_tax( price float) return float
....
return price;
//
delimiter ;
```

If i try to use this function right now like this

```
select  return_tax(100);
```

nothing happends. And no any errors shown. But if i logout from mysql environment by ...=> \q; and login again and

```
=>use My_database;
=> select return_tax(100);
```

my function is working properly!
Question: Can i start using my function return_tax without logging out, just after creating procedure? My server is: MySQL Community Server 5.6.35. I'm using pre-installed MySQL login command line./MySQL Workbench. Thnx.

Comment: Normally , this should work. I can't think of any reason why this isn't working. You don't have to re-login to use a function.

Comment: The first return has a syntax error. It should be 'returns float'. I hope it's just a typo...